Problems with special characters using lv_textarea_add_text(ta, "á")
The function lv_textarea_add_text(ta, "á") doesn't display special characters in the text area. What could be the issue?
I tried using the function lv_textarea_add_text(ta, "á") to add the text "á" to the text area. I expected the text area to display the character "á" correctly. However, the special character did not display as expected.

Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share what is displayed instead of common phrase the special character did not display as expected. E.g. (merely my guess) Ã¡? or ├í?

Most likely, the charset you are using to save your source code file doesn't match the charset that your compiler is expecting, and/or that LVGL is expecting in the UI. Have you tried saving the file as UTF-8, telling the compiler the file is UTF-8, adding the u8 prefix in front of the string literal, etc?

I am still encountering issues with displaying special characters in the text area. My source code is saved in UTF-8 encoding. Here is an example of how I am trying to use it:
"lv_textarea_add_text(gui_text_area, u8"ééééééé\n");"
Despite this, the characters are not displayed correctly. Attached is a screenshot of the text area showing the problem: □□□□□□□

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The character you are trying to display in not within the ASCII range.
To add special character/symbol (Unicode), you need to add font to your project by using any of below methods:

Go to lvgl online font converter and upload a font that supports Unicode characters. Make sure to specify the correct Unicode range (e.g.  Latin Extended-A) when converting the font.
By using offline font converter available in directory lvgl/scripts/

Apply added font using:
lv_obj_set_style_text_font(ta, &ADDED_FONT, LV_PART_MAIN | LV_STATE_DEFAULT);
Note: The above API is valid for lvgl version 9.0.0. A similar API is available in other versions, also maybe with different API name.
